# Postgres Row Level Security and BDR

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, row-level-security, postgresql-bdr

I am implementing a multi tenant web app using postgres. I want to use Row Level Security (RLS ) for data separation. RLS is available from PG version 9.5. However, at the same time, the HA / DR teams plan to use BDR ( Bi directional replication) for the HA solution. It seems that BDR is not yet supported in 9.5.

- What can be done in such a scenario ?
- Is it possible to get BDR on 9.5 ?
- What other replication strategies provide the same benefits as BDR?

Yes, schemas is also an approach, but I am already using that for tables which have less data. I want RLS for tables that will eventually get enormous, so replicating them in different schemas wont be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve BDR (in the PostgreSQL) use is pgPool, which has multi-master replication with failover.
For a complete tutorial, please use the official product site or wiki even at the addresses below:

- **pgpool**

http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pgpool-II